# How can I retrieve values from included PHP contants with conflicting names?

Tags: php, namespaces, include, constants

I have found a couple of similar questions, but I've got a slightly different nuance--namely, I cannot edit the included files.

I've got a directory, with dozens of clones of the same php application.  I need to read each config file, which is a php file that defines database settings as constants, then connect to that instance's DB.  Obviously, since all the config files are for the same application, looping through the directories and including all the config files gives me 100's of "Constant DB_HOST already defined" notices.

This would be easy enough if I could prepend a php namespace to each of the config files, but I cannot modify the config files, only read them.  Since it's impossible to build the namespaces within the loop reading the directory contents, I'm stuck.

Aside from reading the file with fopen/file_get_contents and re-parsing the contents, is there some ingenious way to loop through these config files to include their constant values?  I feel like I must be overlooking something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using include on each of the files, couldn't you simply open each of them as a text file and read the contents of each file into a string using `fread()`?

That will let you then parse out the fields you want using regular expressions, and since you're not including the config files as PHP, you'll sidestep the constant issue.

Comment: I would have loved to see another solution that allowed PHP to parse the file, rather than doing it myself, but this was ultimately the only option.  Despite the fact that I mentioned not wanting to do this in my question, this is the closest thing to an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a TERRIFIC DESIGN problem, and should be solved by altering design, not by silly trick solving constant problem leaving the whole mess intact.

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately the app instances aren't under my control, so I've got no choice but to leave that part in tact.

Answer (score 0):

You are not overlooking anything. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> Once a constant is defined, it can never be changed or undefined.

And BTW, I hope for you that you can get a project for refactoring that mess approved. :)

Comment: I wish.  Unfortunately, dozens of instances of the app itself isn't under my control, I just have to wrap around it without touching it. (grumble)